# How to dynamically configure Nginx load balancer to send specific requests one server

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, ruby, unicorn

For the purpose of debugging and testing, I am looking at ways to send requests pertaining a particular, say customer ID, from the Nginx load balancer to a specified machine. I am using Nginx on my own server. I am using Unicorn as well as Puma on some instance as my web-server.

Comment: Let you check if you can use application load balancer and the listeners with rules or session stickiness. Also, for debugging, you can suspend all but one instance. Another option is to connect directly to the instance or to add a listener on another port with the only given instance in its own target group. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#listener-rules

Comment: Lenin, please edit your question to be more precise. Are you talking about AWS ELB, or Nginx on an instance? If it's not ELB, please don't call it ELB. I don't think you're talking about AWS because of tagging. Instead of "say customer ID" tell us exactly how you want to do it. By path would be easy, but if you want it by cookie presence, cookie value, etc, that might change things.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Tim. I am talking about Nginx being used as an ELB(or say a reverse proxy?) on an instance. It is not an AWS ELB. I am also using Nginx on my instances along with a web server.
I am fairly new to software development(< 1 year). What I am trying to say is that in the app, we get events on the ELB,and it can send it on any instance. For the cases of one-box prod testing, it would be mighty convenient if there was a way by which we could configure the ELB to send the requests pertaining to one particular key to that particular box. Sorry I am not able to explain clearly.

Comment: Thank You Petr. I will try looking into this approach.

Comment: In this case are you trying to test the server or the load balancer? In testing you can just directly address the individual machine, or you can edit the Nginx config to ensure there's only one machine in the cluster. If you're testing in production while users are using it (which is generally a bad idea) then you probably do need to do this, but you'd be better off having a test setup that's separate.